# How to group by number of documents in buckets in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a way to group by the number of documents in buckets after a terms aggregation?
My terms aggregation looks like this:

```
"aggs": {
        "values": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "number"
            }
        }
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
...
        {
          "key" : "12345",
          "doc_count" : 99
        },
        {
          "key" : "123456",
          "doc_count" : 99
        },
        {
          "key" : "112233",
          "doc_count" : 6
        },
        {
          "key" : "334455",
          "doc_count" : 6
        },
        {
          "key" : "456789",
          "doc_count" : 5
        }
...
```

And what I want to have is something like this:

```
...
        {
          "doc_count" : "99",
          "buckets" : 2
        }, 
       {
          "doc_count" : "6",
          "buckets" : 2
        },
        {
          "doc_count" : "5",
          "buckets" : 1
        }
...
```

Is there an easy way in Elasticsearch to get this result?

Comment: Can you do it in your application?

Comment: didn't manage to do it yet...